# Linux file synchronization between computers

Tags: linux, synchronization, remote-access, data-synchronization

I'm looking for a software which will allow me to synchronize files in specyfic folders between my linux boxes. I have searched a lot of topics and what I've found is Unison. It looks prety good but it is not under development anymore and does not allow me to see file change history. 
So the question is - what is the best linux file synchronizer, that:

1. (required) will synchronize only selected folders
2. (required) will synchronize computers at given time (for example each hour)
3. (required) will be intelligent - will remember what was deleted and when and will ask me if I want to delete it on remote machine too.
4. (optionally) will keep track of changes and allow to see history of changes
5. (optionally) will be multiplatform

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Rsync](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rsync) is probably the de facto.

I see Unison is based on Rsync -- not sure if Rsync alone can achieve number 3 above.

Also, see [this article](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/aix/library/au-rsyncfamily/index.html) with detailed information about rsync, including available GUI's for it.

Comment: thank you, great article! there is problem with these guis - all of them are in "work in progress" giving you limited and not stable functionality. rsync cannot (correct me if i am wrong) track deleted files -only new, so it is not good solution.

Answer (score 3):

While I agree Rsync is defacto swissknife for linux users, I found 2 other projects more interesting especially for use case where I have 2 workstations in different locations and laptop, all 3 machines for work, so I felt pain here. I found really nice project called:
https://syncthing.net/

I run it on public server with vpn access where my machines are always connected and it simply works. It has gui for monitoring purposes (basic, but enough infor available)

Second is paid, but with similar functionality on top built in:
https://www.resilio.com/

Answer (score 1):

Osync is probably what you're looking for (see http://www.netpower.fr/osync )
Osync is actually rsync based but will handle number 3 above without trouble.
Number 4, keeping track of modified files can be more or less achieved by adding --verbose parameter which will log file updates.
Actually, only number 5 won't work. Osync runs on most unix flavors but not windows.